# Function should return all objects stored in the mapping array

Tags: solidity, remix

Here's my solidity code. And I want all the objects to be returned stored in mapping array `contracts` in the `getContract` method by giving address as a parameter to the `getContract` function.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract company {

    struct contractDetails {
        string contractId;
        string companyA;
        string companyB;
        address A;
        address B;
        uint256 timestamp;
        string signHash;
        bool isSigned;
    }

    mapping (string => contractDetails) contracts;
    mapping (string => string) hashMap;

    event contractSigned (
        string contractId,
        string companyA,
        string companyB,
        address A,
        address B,
        uint256 timestamp,
        string signHash,
        bool isSigned
    );

    function createContract(string memory _contractId, string memory _companyA, string memory _companyB, address _B) public {
        contracts[_contractId] = contractDetails(_contractId, _companyA, _companyB, msg.sender, _B, now, '', false);
    }

    function signContract(string memory _contractId) public {
        contractDetails storage signDetails = contracts[_contractId];
        signDetails.isSigned = true;
        signDetails.timestamp = now;
        emit contractSigned(_contractId, signDetails.companyA, signDetails.companyB, signDetails.A, signDetails.B, signDetails.timestamp, signDetails.signHash, signDetails.isSigned);
    }

    function verifySign(string memory _contractId) public view returns(bool) {
        contractDetails storage verify = contracts[_contractId];
        return(verify.isSigned);
    }

    function getContract(address _address) view public returns(/* Array containing all objects */) {
      /* Code Here */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should clarify what is the `_address` address that you pass to the `getContract()` function.

Anyway, there is no good way of viewing all the mapping's elements.
But there are some options:

1. Use dynamically sized array. It is easier to show all the elements, however, the elemend can be accessed only by `uint` id. It is suitable for you if 
   `_contractId` is actually a number. Also, there will appear 'holes' in the array in case you want to remove contracts.
2. Use mapping + array. It is a popular solution in smart-contracts, however not perfect. You can place your structure members in a mapping to easily get them by `string` key, and also put them in the array to easily show them all. This solution is not gas-efficient and is prone to mistakes when adding/removing elements. In your case, you can store just `_contractId`'s in the array.

Overall, showing all the elements is rather costly operation and may not fit the block size. So, in case the array is used it is better to add the functionality to show the elements of the array partially.